# Excel Vba Code to Check Quantity in a Column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro to format a spreadsheet. I need some excel vba code to add to the start to check that the `Quantity` in a column is always '1'

The code needs to check the column from cell H2 to the bottom of the data in H2 (until it finds a blank cell).

If all the values are '1' do nothing and continue running the macro. If it finds any other number (either negative or positive) display a `MsgBox "Warning: Quantities Other Than '1' Found. Fix Errors and Re-Run!"` then when 'OK' is selected exit the macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub YourExistingCode()
    If QuantityErrorFound Then
        MsgBox "Warning: Quantities Other Than '1' Found. Fix Errors and Re-Run!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        '~~> Run your code
    End If
End Sub

Function QuantityErrorFound() As Boolean
    Dim cl As Range, result As Boolean

    result = False

    For Each cl In Range("H2:H" & Range("H2").End(xlDown).Row)
        If cl.Value <> 1 Then
            result = True
        End If
    Next cl

    QuantityErrorFound = result
End Function
```

1. I've used a function (`QuantityErrorFound`) to make it easier to integrate into your existing code
2. In your existing code simply add the `if` statement to check whether an error is found

Answer (score 0):

Just a slight change to Alex P's code really. As you're dealing with `1`s a simple sum will be quicker than a loop

```
Function QuantityErrorFound() As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean
    Dim lastR as long
    Dim sumCells as long
    Dim cntCells as Long 
    result = False

    'lastR = Range("H2").End(xlDown).Row
    lastR= Cells(rows.count, Range("H2").Column).End(Excel.xlUp).Row  '<< assuming below the last cell is empty then this is a better approach to above line.

    sumCells = Excel.Application.Sum(Range("H2:H" & lastR))
    cntCells = Range("H2:H" & lastR).cells.count
    if (sumCells = cntCells) then
       result = True
    end if

    QuantityErrorFound = result
End Function
```

Personally in my work spreadsheets I would use a formula in a hidden cell (named range called "ErrorCheck") like this:

```
=if(countif(H2:H10000,"<>1")>0,"error","ok")
```

Then in my `vba` all I need is the following:

```
if ((range("ErrorCheck") = "error") then
   MsgBox "Warning: Quantities Other Than '1' Found. Fix Errors and Re-Run!"
else
   ...
   ...
```

---

**Edit**

Please see flaw in my check as pointed out by Ian Cook. I will leave the code as is - but you should force values in column H to be either 1 or 0 if using the above. This could be done with a simple formula:

```
=if(<current formula>=1,1,0)
```

or

```
=1*(<current formula>=1)
```

Or, defend Ian's possible problem, by changing the `Sum` in my `vba` to a `countIf`:

```
Function QuantityErrorFound() As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean
    Dim lastR as long
    Dim sumCells as long
    Dim cntCells as Long 
    result = False

    'lastR = Range("H2").End(xlDown).Row
    lastR= Cells(rows.count, Range("H2").Column).End(Excel.xlUp).Row  '<< assuming below the last cell is empty then this is a better approach to above line.

    sumCells = Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H" & lastR),"=1")  '<<not tested and may need to read ...,1)
    cntCells = Range("H2:H" & lastR).cells.count
    if (sumCells = cntCells) then
       result = True
    end if

    QuantityErrorFound = result
End Function
```

Then again if using the above it could be simplified to the following:

```
Function QuantityErrorFound() As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean
    Dim lastR as long
    Dim sumCells as long
    result = False

    lastR= Cells(rows.count, Range("H2").Column).End(Excel.xlUp).Row 

    sumCells = Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H" & lastR),"<>1")  
    if (sumCells = 0) then
       result = True
    end if

    QuantityErrorFound = result
End Function
```

Comment: Good shout - yes checking sum against row count is a neater way

Comment: Should the 4 values 3,2,0,-1 which sum to 4 pass validation ?

Comment: @IanCook Better shout - there could be problems with my idea. I'll edit with this possible error but I'll leave as is, just in case the questioner can force values in the target range to be either 1 or 0 (and no other value)

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your code. I have this working ok, however I could not get it working in the same macro as the code I already had. I just created a Private Sub and used Call to run from this. Not sure if there is a neater way of doing this but it works fine.